# WL 6.1 Is it possible to display at the same time web and native views?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a customer that is requesting to display at the same time web views and native views. For example with tablets in landscape, display a vertical web menu at the left and a native view as the main view.

With WL.NativePage.show() all the UI is native.

Is there any way for doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add native controls to one part of the screen, resize the CordovaWebView, and then implement communication between the two. Check out this blog by Anton Aleksandrov:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/android_combining_native_and_web_controls_in_cordova_based_applications?lang=en